# Chrome 69.x background-size cover minimum heights?

Tags: css, google-chrome

It seems that in chrome 69.x, there's a bug (or change) related to `background-size: cover`.

If you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ah1dqg3n/ when the height is `50px` there's no background showing, however with a `500px` height the background image is showing.

Any ideas if this is related to an explicit change chrome has made or if there's a new "correct" solution for this when needed in smaller content areas?

Comment: That is so interesting, probably a bug, but works with any other image tested.

Comment: @Stickers seems to not work with 1x1 pixel images, other ones too.  Seems like combination bug between image size and height size.